# Builder about to fit beading, is he doing it right?

Tags: flooring

My builder is about to fit beading around the edges of my wood floor, next to the Victorian bay window.

He's cut these pieces (see photos).

Should I ask him to carve into the beading to fit around the original detail? Or use some filler? Or something else?[image]

Comment: Will depend on how much you want to pay.  That craving/cutting will not be a fast job, depending on the tools and matching, maybe an hour or more for those couple of inches.

Comment: Is the beading intended to be finished (painted?) at all?

Comment: Plan to filler and paint

Answer (score 1):

That looks pretty bad. To do it right, he'd need a deeper piece of beading there because the front edges won't match if the curved cuts are made in the back. It would be a custom fit. I doubt they would do it. You'd need a fourth generation carpenter. What does the contract state about this. If it's left this way, you could get some matching wood filler to fill in the spaces.

Comment: Wood filler it is. The contract is rubbish :(

Comment: @mcintyre321  I'd be curious how they finish off that corner.  Slide paper under the beading when painting to save the floor..  :-)